# QT Creator compiler crashing (MSVC 2015, Qt 5.8)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, qt-creator

I'm new to C++ and programming, and trying to work on a little project, using Qt/Qt Creator .

I was using the MinGW compiler, but especially for this project I will need to use the MSVC compiler (since I need QtWebEngineWidgets).

I have Qt 5.8 and I'm using Qt Creator. I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Community), and also installed wdk and winsdk 2015 (1703 version) from Microsft's website. It took a while!

So, I added the compiler and the debugger to the kit, but Qmake is still crashing.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Compilers]

[image: Debuggers]

[image: Kits with my current parameters]

[image: The QMake error message, in french but easy to understand]

If you need me to provide more informations about this issue, just ask for it and I will try my best.

Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see qmake crashing. I see that qmake completed its work properly. I see microsoft compiler crashing there.

Is it possible you're using 32bit build of Qt with a 64bit microsoft compiler? I see the crash is from amd64_x86/cl.exe but in the image I see 32bit msvc2015 Qt is selected.

Comment: I followed your advise and modified the kit to make it work as x64 and it now works!

Still can't launch my program because of a different problem (C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWebEngineWidgets': No such file or directory), but the it doesn't look to be the same. 

Thank you!